# Q: react-router - component rendering - maybe logic wrong

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Maybe my understanding of react-router is not there or my logic is wrong or I'm missing the critical part.

```
from App.js 

    function App() {
      return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
          <Header/>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about' exact component={About}/>
            <Route path='/services' exact component={Services}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <ContentSection/>
        <Footer/>
      </>
      );
    }
```

from Header.js

```
function Header() {
  return (
   <>
    <header>
      <div className='logo'>logo</div>
      <Nav/>
    </header>
   </>
  );
}
    export default Header;
```

from Nav.js

```
function Nav() {
  return (
   <>
    <ul className='menu'>
      <li className='menu-item'>   
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li className='menu-item'>   
          <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
      </li>
      <li className='menu-item'>   
          <Link to='/services'>Services</Link>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

The url changes but where  should render the component based on nav option/link selected, it doesn't render anything.  Do I need to put the selected link into state and pass it to the component as a prop? IF anyone has a good tutorial links - appreciate that too.

Thanks.

Comment: Take header out of router and keep only the `<Route />` inside switch and try again

Comment: Error: "You should not use <Link> outside of <Router>"

Comment: Because you `Nav` component is not inside Router

Comment: I updated the code sequence in original question, maybe you can't nest the links that far down?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Router` is a provider, it should wrap around every component that uses a `Route` or a `Switch` or any `react-router` component:

```
function App() {
  return (
  <>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' exact component={About}/>
        <Route path='/services' exact component={Services}/>
    </Router>
    <Header />
    <ContentSection/>
    <Footer/>
  </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your Header outside of Switch

```
      <>
        <Router>
          <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about' exact component={About}/>
            <Route path='/services' exact component={Services}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <ContentSection/>
        <Footer/>
      </>
```

how Switch works in react router [Use of Switch](https://medium.com/@AkyunaAkish/understanding-react-router-4-df73a66d96c4)